# Wrong image & tekst Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, opencart, addthis

I'm using Facebook Like on my product pages. When somebody like's a product the wrong tekst and image is displayed on the Timeline of the User. Pinterest and Twitter are working okay.

I use Opencart version 1.5.2.1 and my buttons are from Addthis. The Pinterest button is modified for Opencart. The code i use is:

> `<div class="share"><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --> <div
>   class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "> <a
>   class="addthis_button_pinterest" pi:pinit:url=<?php echo
>   $breadcrumb['href']; ?> pi:pinit:media=<?php echo $thumb; ?>
>   pi:pinit:layout="none"></a> <a class="addthis_button_tweet"
>   tw:count="none"></a> <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"
>   fb:like:width="85"  /></a> </div> <script type="text/javascript"
>   src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f68526319f4252e"></script>
>   <!-- AddThis Button END -->`

If someone is able to help me with this it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a user agent problem.

Facebook was not able to see my page.

It is solved now by putting the user agent in array.